# Oralce no data found and other error

Tags: oracle

Can somebody help me out regarding the following two queries?

1. When I am trying to execute select query on a view through my application using Pro*C, I am getting the error no data found even though the data is there. There is no problem with the query. But when I am connecting to some other database and executing the same query, there is no problem. Can somebody help me out in this?
2. When I am connecting to a particular database from a Linux server, I am getting table or view does not exist error. When when I am connecting to the same database from other linux server, I am getting no data found. Why is such kind of difference there? Even though I have the same permissions on  both the Linux servers.

Comment: Are you connecting to the database as the user that owns the objects you're querying?

Answer (score 1):

Given (1) and (2), I'd suspect that you are connecting to different users in the same database or (more likely) different databases.

Check the TNSNAMES.ORA on all machines and see where they are directing you to.

You can also check v$instance and v$database once you are connected to confirm you are where you think you are.

and even

```
select utl_inaddr.get_host_address from dual
```

to see what IP address the database server thinks it is running on.

Comment: i am connecting to the same database and with same user name.